# Making Objects In main Class

Tags: java

How may I create an object for a class that has constructor in it?

After I've created a constructor method, the object call I made in my main class is highlighted red and i'm facing an error, how can I overcome this?

for more details , object is trying to be called from "clerck" class in main class, before creating a constructor in "Clerck" class , everything was ok , and this object were working fine , but after that , it's highlighted red , showing an error.

```
   Clerck object = New Clerck();
```

the erorr says that arguments needed , which means it's calling my constructor not my class ! , I want my class to be called , so then object is created and a function can be called.

Comment: by posting your code here

Comment: It's a lot , I mean there are two classes , so i'm trying to creating an object for my "clerck" class in my main class,  Clerck object = New Clerck(); if it's what you are seeking for

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: Can you please post the code? It is very difficult to help if we are not clear as to what you are asking.

Comment: Yes , you guys are all right , I've rephrased and added more details to my question

Comment: why for gods sake don't you just add some code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have written the "new" Keyword with a capital letter.
Try

```
Clerck object = new Clerck();
```

instead.

Comment: That's not the problem , the problem is program is calling my constructor , when ever I try to make an object for my class

Comment: that's the second time someone is posting this answer...maybe it's not really clear what you want to achieve. But i also don't know how you could solve this problem without posting some code.